# Ruby Split string at character difference using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I'm current working on a problem that involves splitting a string by each group of characters.

For example,

```
"111223334456777" #=> ['111','22','333','44','5','6','777']
```

The way I am currently doing it now is using a enumerator and comparing each character with the next one, and splitting the array that way.

```
res = []
str = "111223334456777"
group = str[0]
(1...str.length).each do |i|
  if str[i] != str[i-1]
    res << group
    group = str[i]
  else
    group << str[i]
  end
end
res << group
res #=> ['111','22','333','44','5','6','777']
```

I want to see if I can use regex to do this, which will make this process a lot easier. I understand I could just put this block of code in a method, but I'm curious if regex can be used here.

So what I want to do is

```
str.split(/some regex/)
```

to produce the same result. I thought about positive lookahead, but I can't figure out how to have regex recognize that the character is different.

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you could write `"111223334456777".each_char.slice_when { |a,b| a!=b }.map(&:join)
 #=> ["111", "22", "333", "44", "5", "6", "777"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you code is definitely cleaner than mine, I just wrote that to clarify what I was looking for.

Comment: As per @Stefan's comment on Tadman's answer, above can be simplified to `"111223334456777".each_char.slice_when(&:!=).map(&:join)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = "111333224456777"

str.scan /0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+/
  #=> ["111", "333", "22", "44", "5", "6", "777"]
```

or

```
str.gsub(/(\d)\1*/).to_a
  #=> ["111", "333", "22", "44", "5", "6", "777"]
```

The latter uses the (underused) form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument and no block, returning an enumerator. It merely generates matches and has nothing to do with character replacement.

---

For fun, here are several other ways to do that.

```
str.scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map(&:first)
str.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/).each_slice(2).map(&:first)
str.each_char.slice_when(&:!=).map(&:join)
str.each_char.chunk(&:itself).map { |_,a| a.join }
str.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)
str.gsub(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/, ' ').split
str.gsub(/(.)\1*/).reduce([], &:<<)  
str[1..-1].each_char.with_object([txt[0]]) {|c,a| a.last[-1]==c ? (a.last<<c) : a << c}
```

Comment: the second way is perfect, just what i'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `str.chars.chunk_while { |b,a| b == a }.map(&:join)` also works and on arbitrary input as well, perhaps including letters and such.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind the edit. I don't know Ruby, but the collection in the other topic seemed valuable. Perhaps the comment should be copied too, I can't decide if that's something obvious or not.

Comment: @tevemadar, I appreciate the edit very much, though I will do a further small edit to make those other solutions conform to the example string given here. I wasn't aware the later question had been closed. Not simply closed, but the question and all answers were deleted, something I've not seen before, the purpose of which escapes me.

Answer (score 6):

The [`chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) method is what you're looking for here:

```
str.chars.chunk_while { |b,a| b == a }.map(&:join)
```

That will break anything where the current character `a` doesn't match the previous character `b`. If you want to restrict to just numbers you can do some pre-processing.

There's a lot of very handy methods in Enumerable that are worth exploring, and each new version of Ruby seems to add more of them.

Comment: Can be shortened to `str.chars.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)`

Comment: ...or `str.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)` to avoid the creation of the temporary array `str.chars`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which utilises the `group_by` method, which returns a hash with each individual number as a key and an array of grouped numbers as the value.

```
"111223334456777".split('').group_by { |i| i }.values.map(&:join) => => ["111", "22", "333", "44", "5", "6", "777"]
```

Although it doesn't implement a regex, someone else may find it useful.

Comment: Note that this returns `["11", "22", "33"]` for `"123123"`